# Google Charts, combochart, Controls and Dashboards, for row and column

Tags: google-visualization

I have combochart, like in this example
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/combochart

I can bind categoryFilter to it, like in this example
https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#categoryfilter_control

But this only work for 1 dimension, in first example for 'Month', but not for 'Country' . How can i connect categoryFilter to second dimension?

Answer (score 0):

Each filter can only operate on one column of data; to filter on a second column, you need another CategoryFilter.

Comment: Yes, but can i create second filter for ROW, not for second column?

Comment: @ПавелКуликов, the filters work only on columns, not rows.  Could you post an example of what you want your filter to do?